# How to test for stability in sorting algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort, mergesort, insertion-sort

I'm currently trying to see if the algorithms I have wrote are stable. Most of my tests consist of creating an unsorted array of integer objects, cloning it, running my sort on the former version and arrays.sort on the one I want to be correctly sorted. Basically am wondering if there is a way with Integer objects or another data type that I can test for stability in my implementations of merge, insertion and others? Disproving it is fine too, I just want to see if I have written a defect in and thus its not stable.

:Any object types work really, Im just using integers currently for ease of testing.

Comment: No, if you are sorting primitives, you can't disinguish whether there were sorted using stable or unstable algorithm just by looking at them. You *could* use pairs of [element, starting position], but that could only disprove the stability, not prove it. To prove it, you need to run some math analysis. I recomment reading about *mathematical induction* or, to simplify, read [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-mathematically-prove-stability-in-sorting-algorithms).

Comment: @Fureeish: The OP says (s)he is sorting "integer objects" -- *not* primitives.

Comment: @ruakh, if the OP indeed is using `Integer`s instead of `int`s, one can play with reference semantics (although be careful regarding `Integer`s from `-128` to `127`, since they are optimised), but the general point stands. Using reference semantics one can only *dis*prove the stability of an algorithm. To prove it, one must do so mathematically.

Comment: @Fureeish: But the OP didn't ask how to "prove" it, (s)he asked how to "test for" it -- presumably meaning, how to write unit-test verifications that confirm that a given call to his/her "sort" method didn't swap the order of any two equivalent elements.

Comment: @ruakh "*I'm currently trying to see if the algorithms I have wrote are stable*" is the very first sentence of the question. It implies that OP wants to... check if the algorithm (s)he wrote is stable. If (s)he wants to do so by testing whether a particular sample data mainained stability after a particular sort call, it got some bad, bad news. That's why I keep stressing the proof importance. I do not think the essence of the question is to check whether a ***particular*** call mainainted stability.

Comment: @ruakh I am well aware of what unit testing is. Unfortunately, unit tests have nothing to do with the problem here. The very first sentence of OP's question states that they want to test for stability. Unless your unit test can prove (for example, by induction) that the algorithm is stable, the result will be valid only for a given data sample. You do not check for stability of an algorithm by running a unit test. You prove it mathematically. Everything what I say here is based on the assumption that OP wants to check *if the algorithm is stable*, not *if a particular call maitained stability*

Comment: @Fureeish: You've invented a problem that isn't what the OP asked for, and then complained that it can't be done in the way the OP asks about. It's completely legitimate to point out that unit-testing has limitations, but it's absurd to claim without evidence that the OP is using the words "test" and "see" to refer to mathematical proofs rather than to, y'know, tests. (Especially since the OP has already made quite clear how (s)he's testing that the method does sorting, and is just asking how to do the same for testing stability.)

Comment: @ruakh you seem to miss the point here and drive the discussion away from the topic. The fact that OP did not use the word "proof" does not mean they don't have it in mind. I interpret "*trying to see if the algorithms I have wrote are stable*" as "*how can I check if my algorithm is stable?*" You **can't** do that with unit testing and OP could as well be unaware of that fact, that's why I wrote what I wrote. But since I used the word "discussion", it means that we misused the comment section. Feel free to invite me to chat and we can try to work out the misconceptions there.

Comment: @Fureeish: I think it's you who are missing the point and driving the discussion away from the topic. I don't think there are any "misconceptions" here; it's just that you've somehow misinterpreted the OP's question as asking for something quite different from what it's plainly asking for.

Comment: @Fureeish  I'm testing for a specific set of values to see if stability was maintained through unit tests. The set of values doesn't really matter I just need to know if I can in fact test to see if an algorithim is unstable. Then I can fix it.

Comment: This seems extremely unclear. If you have a specific set of values, why use an algorithm to sort them and test for stability? Maintaining stability through a number of unit tests gives you absolutely no information about any further usage. What's the point of unit testing a stability of the algorithm? What are you trying to achieve? No matter how many unit tests you run, you cannot be sure your algorithm is stable (unless you provide all possible permutations, which is unlikely).

Comment: I would highly recommend changing your tags to better suite the content the question is asking. For example quicksort, etc aren't related to your question; however, sorting and mathematics would be. This would help you find answers more in line with what you're asking.

Comment: @Fureeish It is an exercise to find code defects in a given algorithm in this scenario.

Comment: Ah, so happy find some clarifications! So, to summarize - you've been given an algorithm and were assigned to test whether it was indeed stable? Were you given a specific data to check whether the algorithm maintains stability when sorting it, or is it a general assignment "test this algorithm for stability"?

Comment: @Fureeish Yeah that's the gist of this exercise basically, and theres no specifc rules for test data, the algorithm sorts arrays of generics types and we're tasked with finding which algorithms that are supposed to be stable are not in fact stable through the use of unit testing.

Comment: So you actually want to prove that an algorithm is *not* stable. That sort of clashes with the first sentence of your question. Remember - you can disprove something by finding just one counterexample, but you cannot prove something by doing tests one by one. Disproving then will be easier - either try to find a specific data which breaks the algorithm (may never work) or disprove it mathematically. As for checking whether a particular sorting call was stable, see **Not a JD**'s answer, but remember that the particular sequence (s)he provided may not work. See my (8th total) comment there.

Comment: @Fureeish - similar to Fureeish's first comment, you could logically split an integer into two parts. The upper bits would be random, the lower bits would be the index within the array. The compare used for the sort would only compare the upper bits. The upper bit range would need to be limited so there would be a relatively large number of duplicates. Then a post sort check could be done to test for failure. This would only detect a failure, it wouldn't prove the sort is stable.  As already commented, an analysis of the algorithm would be needed for proof.

Comment: As an example of a somewhat complicated analysis used to show that a sort is stable, take a look at [wiki block merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort#Stability), which is an in-place and stable merge sort with O(n log(n)) time complexity. The trick here is to swap only unique values within the array or move only the first instances of non-unique values to the left of the array to create working space for merge operations. If there are less than sqrt(n) unique values in a array, smaller working space is used, increasing time constant, but time complexity remains O(n log(n)).

Comment: Some general cases - bubble sort is stable because all swaps involve adjacent elements. quicksort is normally not stable because swaps involve non-adjacent elements. Insertion sort is stable because it inserts first instances first (or it only swaps adjacent elements). Standard merge sort is stable because it only uses merge operations. Hybrid insertion and merge sort is stable because both insertion sort and merge sort are stable. The analysis in these examples is not that complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Generally when someone wants to prove an algorithm for correctness they could start out trying to prove this by strong induction. Please note that any test case is just that, a test for a particular case. It doesn't prove what you wrote is correct for all cases. That is why induction comes into play.

Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction 
Given the question's phrasing I would also recommend you give `Algorithms by Sanjoy Dasgupta, Christos H. Papadimitriou, and Umesh Vazirani` a read

Edit: 
if you want to prove your algorithm is wrong then you can do this by proof of incorrectness. In other words find a case where the algorithm fails.

You could also check all sequences for an array of even size and then for odd size. This would be to see if the expected results holds for all possible combinations positioned in a list. Then again what about a previous case of the current size plus 1 or plus 2? Which leads back to induction.

Comment: It's clear from the question that the OP is *not* trying to "prove an algorithm for correctness"; rather, (s)he is trying to write or update a test case to add assertions about stability. You mention that tests are no substitute for proofs, and I agree, but the reverse is true as well: proofs are no substitute for tests, because it's very common to design everything correctly and then make a small mistake in implementation.

Comment: What case is the individual trying to find to be stable? I suppose would be the question. Generally we got unit, integration, and regression testing. Now for an algorithm how are you going to test all cases? You could perhaps compare results to something trusted. But then why aren't we using the existing library?

Comment: Re: "You could perhaps compare results to something trusted": And that is exactly what the OP wrote in his/her question: "Most of my tests consist of creating an unsorted array of integer objects, cloning it, **running** my sort on the former version and **arrays.sort** on the one I want to be correctly sorted" [emphasis mine]. Re: "But then why aren't you using the existing library?": In the OP's case this is probably a learning exercise; but in the real world, too, it's not too unusual to test a complicated approach against a slower-but-known-correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck with Integers as you'll have issues with object identity.

A strategy like this might work for you - really simple, just encapsulate an Integer, sort (I use `Collections.sort()` below - it's guaranteed to be stable) and ensure the elements in the `List` correspond to stable element order in the `objs` array.

```
public class StableValidation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntegerWrapper[] objs = new IntegerWrapper[] { new IntegerWrapper(1), new IntegerWrapper(2), new IntegerWrapper(3),
                new IntegerWrapper(2) };

        // sort
        List<IntegerWrapper> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(objs));
        Collections.sort(list);

        System.out.println(list.get(1) == objs[1]);
        System.out.println(list.get(2) == objs[3]);
    }
}

class IntegerWrapper implements Comparable<IntegerWrapper> {
    private int i;

    public IntegerWrapper(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(IntegerWrapper that) {
        return Integer.compare(this.i, that.i);
    }
}
```

Yields:

```
true
true
```

Comment: How does this test for stability of an algorithm, which is the essence of the (*too broad*) question?

Comment: I don't have to use to integer objects tbh, the algorithm is designed with the intent of any generic arrays of type T, Im currently just using integer objects for ease of testing.

Comment: +1, though I don't quite understand why you've created a new `IntegerWrapper` type rather than using the JDK's `Integer` type (e.g. `new Integer(3)`).

Comment: @ruakh because I'm an idiot! For some reason I thought the JVM did some magic and interned even Integer type instantiation. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Perhaps the reason for creating an `int` wrapper as opposed to using `Integer` is the fact that `Integer x1 = 3; Integer x2 = 3; x1 == x2` evaluates to `true`, while `Integer x1 = 333; Integer x2 = 333; x1 == x2` evaluates to `false`, due to optimisations regarding storage, thus resulting in inconsistencies regarding checking references equalities. But that might not be the case.

Comment: @Fureeish: That's because `Integer x1 = 3` uses `Integer.valueOf`. But `new Integer(3)` has no such optimization. There's no need for a separate `IntegerWrapper`.

Comment: @ruakh that's why I noted that it might not be the case. The situation depends on how you create the values. But you are correct on your explanation.

Comment: Plus, this solution may not work. There can be an unstable algorithm which will sort this very sequence (`1, 2, 3, 2`) such that it will maintain stable order.